# Speeding up S3 to GCS transfer using GCE and gsutil

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I plan on using a GCE cluster and gsutil to transfer ~50Tb of data from Amazon S3 to GCS. So far I have a good way to distribute the load over however many instances I'll have to use but I'm getting pretty slow transfer rates in comparison to what I achieved with my local cluster. Here are the details of what I'm doing

**Instance type:** n1-highcpu-8-d

**Image:** debian-6-squeeze

**typical load average during jobs:** 26.43, 23.15, 21.15

**average transfer speed on a 70gb test (for a single instance):** ~21mbps

**average file size:** ~300mb

**.boto process count:** 8

**.boto thread count:** 10

Im calling gsutil on around 400 s3 files at a time:

```
gsutil -m cp -InL manifest.txt gs://my_bucket
```

I need some advice on how to make this transfer faster on each instance. I'm also not 100% on whether the n1-highcpu-8-d instance is the best choice. I was thinking of possibly parallelizing the job myself using python, but I think that tweaking the gsutil settings could yield good results. Any advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're seeing 21Mbps per object and running around 20 objects at a time, you're getting around 420Mbps throughput from one machine.  On the other hand, if you're seeing 21Mbps total, that suggests that you're probably getting throttled pretty heavily somewhere along the path.

I'd suggest that you may want to use multiple smaller instances to spread the requests across multiple IP addresses; for example, using 4 n1-standard-2 instances may result in better total throughput than one n1-standard-8.  You'll need to split up the files to transfer across the machines in order to do this.

I'm also wondering, based on your comments, how many streams you're keeping open at once.  In most of the tests I've seen, you get diminishing returns from extra threads/streams by the time you've reached 8-16 streams, and often a single stream is at least 60-80% as fast as multiple streams with chunking.

One other thing you may want to investigate is what download/upload speeds you're seeing; copying the data to local disk and then re-uploading it will let you get individual measurements for download and upload speed, and using local disk as a buffer might speed up the entire process if gsutil is blocking reading from one pipe due to waiting for writes to the other one.

One other thing you haven't mentioned is which zone you're running in.  I'm presuming you're running in one of the US regions rather than an EU region, and downloading from Amazon's us-east S3 location.

Comment: I was considering running it on multiple instances in the first place, so I think that I will go with your advice and make each of those instances smaller/cheaper since they will probably achieve more per dollar spent. I may not go on an in depth investigation on the up/download speeds of the instances because of time constraints and the low overall cost of the transfer with current performance, but I will look into the zones of the GCE machines I use. Do you have any idea of how I can find out the GS zone I will be uploading to?

Comment: Sorry, I missed this response; you can choose the location that a Google Cloud Storage bucket will be located in when creating the bucket: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques#specifyinglocations

You can find the location of an existing bucket with the command: `gsutil ls -L -b gs://my-bucket/`

Answer (score 0):

use the parallel_thread_count and parallel_process_count values in your boto configuration (usually, ~/.boto) file.

You can get more info on the -m option by typing:

gsutil help options